# DOM Quiz will give incorrect answers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning DOM and wanted to create a simple JavaScript with Html quiz (for exercise). Now the problem I'm having is that when I hit submit, all of the answers are right instead of one being right and 3 being wrong. I think it is a problem with my html and the way I assigned the ID's to the different tags but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Code

### HTML

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css">

  </head>

  <body>

<div class="QuestionOne">
  <form id="quizForm">
<h1> What is your favorite color?</h1>

<input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
<label for="red">Red</label><br>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
<label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
<label for="green">Green</label>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="color" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</div>





<script src="quiz.js">

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
quizForm.addEventListener("submit",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var grabAnswer = document.getElementById('red')
  console.log(grabAnswer.id);


  if (grabAnswer.id == 'red') {
    console.log('correct!');
  }else{
    console.log('wrong');
  }


})
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should get value of checked radio button and then compare that value with `red` .

Comment: You can do this two ways - get the selected value and see if it's correct *or* get the correct answer and see if it's selected.  Your original code gets the correct and answer and sees if it's got the correct answer - which it always will be, by definition - regardless of what's been selected.   You've done "get A and see if it's A".

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? And how is this problem related to CSS?

Comment: I never mentioned that the problem was related to CSS I was thinking it was something about the way I used the ID's but I didn't approach it the right way, I should've get the selected value instead.

Comment: @NicoHaase it's a common issue for people new to asking questions.  The [ask question] page states *"Add up to 5 tags to describe what your question is about"* - so people add extra tags (normally to try to make it to 5) even if their question is only *about* 1 of those tags.

Comment: @mamadubah the tags are there so the relevant people can help answer your question.  The tip on the [ask question] pages says they should read as *"My question is about [tag]"* - so by adding [css] tag you have stated "My problem[question] is about css".   I've removed the offending tag.

Comment: Oh I see, I am not an active user on stack overflow so I wasn't aware of that, Apologies for the inconvenience, I will keep it in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this two ways

1. get the selected value and see if it's correct
2. get the correct answer and see if it's selected

The existing answer handles (1) so here's the solution for the other option.

Taking your original code, change

```
if (grabAnswer.id == 'red') {
```

to

```
if (grabAnswer.checked) {
```

(where `grabAnswer` is `document.getElementById('red')`)

```js
quizForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // get the correct answer
  var grabAnswer = document.getElementById('red')

  // see if it's been selected
  if (grabAnswer.checked) {
    console.log('correct!');
  } else {
    console.log('wrong');
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="QuestionOne">
  <form id="quizForm">
    <h1> What is your favorite color?</h1>

    <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
    <label for="red">Red</label><br>
    <p></p>
    <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
    <p></p>
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
    <label for="green">Green</label>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="color" value="Submit"><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you always take the red in your `grapAnswer`, but you have to use `var grabAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked');`

**Demo**

```js
var quizForm = document.getElementById("quizForm")

quizForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var grabAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked');
  console.log(grabAnswer.id);


  if (grabAnswer.id == 'red') {
    console.log('correct!');
  } else {
    console.log('wrong');
  }


})
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="QuestionOne">
    <form id="quizForm">
      <h1> What is your favorite color?</h1>

      <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
      <label for="red">Red</label><br>
      <p></p>
      <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
      <label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
      <p></p>
      <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
      <label for="green">Green</label>
      <p></p>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="color" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
  </div>





  <script src="quiz.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so you are supposed to grab the answer of whatever is being selected rather than just take in the id?

Comment: Yes, that's one option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> What is your favorite color?</h1>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
<label for="red">Red</label><br>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
<label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
<label for="green">Green</label>
<p></p>
<button type="button" id="button">Submit</button><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
       if($('input[name=color]:checked', '#myForm').val()=='red')
       {
         alert('Succesfully!');
       }
       else
       {
         alert("No");
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can you try this code?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed, and why?

Comment: The friend who wrote the code wrote over javascript, but added jquery in the question. I wrote the jquery version for this

Comment: Please add **all** explanation to your answer by editing it. Also, really **explain** your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will be careful about this